# (OOP) Events in a main loop, and updating dependencies in constructor

Tags: c++, oop

Recently I started a project in hopes to learn OpenGL in C++,and I got stuck on a problem regarding code architecture.

First Question, **should I avoid using events in a main loop?**
Example:

```
Event* UpdateEvent = new Event();

int main(){
   while(1)
       UpdateEvent->Invoke();
}

SomeOtherClass::SomeOtherClass(){
    UpdateEvent->Hook(this->DoSomethingAlways);
}
```

Events from my understanding of C++ code, have a certain amount of penalty in their codes (virtual methods, looping throught events, handling the event stack/array). If i were to implement it in such a way there would definitely be a fair amount of calls on it (Controllers, Coroutines etc.) and this might prove to not be as performant.

Secondly, **Should I avoid subscribing to events / update outside variables in constructor?**

Or should I instead implement factories? Example:

```
//Constructor
MyClass::MyClass(){
    Dependency::Instance->AddObject(this);
}

Dependency::AddObject(MyClass obj){
    InternalList.push(obj);
    InternalEvent.Hook(obj->EventHandler);
}
```

Seen from previous code, I have a habit of subscribing to events in a constructor, and doing other automatic tasks in constructor (Eg. Adding a constructed to some singleton manager). I like doing this because it avoids a need for factories, and creates a little bit more elegant code. But on the other hand, if someone else were to work on this after (Like me in the future) he might not know that certain objects automatically update their dependency objects.

Comment: `Event UpdateEvent = new Event();` is a type error.

Comment: Maybe this is a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I haven't yet implemented an event manager, it serves as an example.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your question. First of all there is no event-system in C++, e.g. no keyword "event". You can of course implement architectural patterns like the the observer pattern. From my point of view, events realize a 1:n relationship between objects. One object notifies some others about some kind of state-change. From an OOP point of view you should make the subscription/unsubscription to/off an event as explicit as possible and not "hide" it in the constructor somewhere.

Comment: @drescherjm when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: You should do only what is **necessary** in a constructor, because it’s impossible to use the class without invoking it.  Forcing its clients to use ”some singleton” damages composability (as well as readability).